# How to construct a new document builder out of an existing builders node?

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-namespaces, xmldom

I have the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory_ = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
Document doc_;
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory_.newDocumentBuilder();
StringReader reader = new StringReader(s);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(reader);
doc_ = dBuilder.parse(inputSource);
doc_.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

and then I traverse `doc_` in order to get a specific node.  I would then like to create a new dBuilder with that node.  What I've been trying so far with little success is to convert my node to a string and then have the `dBuilder.parse` the string but that has not been working because I'm running into namespace problems and other things.

```
<Random>
  <Fixed></Fixed>
</Random>
```

So with this I would take the `<Fixed>` node out and create a completely new class where it is the root node.

Comment: Why can't you just re-use the original `DocumentBuilder`?

Comment: I'm creating a whole new class with the new node.

Comment: I added an edit maybe I was being unclear

Comment: I still don't see why you can't pass the `DocumentBuilder` to the new class

Comment: Because I can't have the <Random> in the doc_ anymore it needs to be just <Fixed> instead of <Random> amd <Fixed>.  Im sorry I don't think im understanding what you are explaining to me.

Comment: why not create new empty doc (reusing your docbuilder) and adopt/import node you're interested in?

Comment: Import was exactly what i needed thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new document and then import your node into it, as shown below:

```
Document otherDoc = dBuilder.newDocument();
Node importedNode = otherDoc.importNode(myNode, true);
otherDoc.appendChild(importedNode);
```